# Counting many to many

Tags: sql, grails, count, many-to-many, hql

I have many to many association between `contact` and `project`.

```
contact:
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

project:
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

project_contact:
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| project_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| contact_id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I would like to count how many contacts are associated with no projects, one project or more than one project. If I could get that in one single query, that'd be absolutely awesome, if not, 3 different queries would do as well.

PS: I am using HQL but I would have no problem in translating the SQL to HQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this a "histogram-of-histograms" query.  It is basically an aggregation on top of an aggregation:

```
select NumProjects, count(*) as NumContacts
from (select c.id, count(pc.contact_id) as NumProjects
      from contacts c left join
           project_contacts pc
           on pc.contact_id = c.id
      group by c.id
     ) c
group by NumProjects
order by NumProjects;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HQL or a criteria query. Assuming a domain model similar to this...

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [contact: Contact]
}

class Contact {
    static hasMany = [project: Project]
    static belongsTo = Project
}
```

### HQL

```
def count = Contact.find('SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Contact AS c WHERE size(c.project) = 0')
```

### Criteria query

```
def count = Contact.createCriteria().get {
    projections {
        count 'id'
    }

    sizeEq 'project', 0
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the contact table has a Set of `ProjectContact` elements, not a set of projects, but thank you for this!